# Getting error while creating enum java class

Tags: java

I am new to Java development and trying to create enum java class in my small project using eclipse IDE.

Getting below error msgs after creating enum java class.

Initially it showed me not compatible with J2SE then I selected compiler compatibility to 1.5., this issue solved.

Getting below 2 error messages after creating enum java class.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.io.ObjectInputStream. Fix the build path then try building this project   Prabu       Unknown Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   Suit.java   /Prabu/src/com  line 1  Java Problem

Comment: It don't think these error messages have anything to do with your enum. Changing the compatibility version probably messed your build config.

Answer (score 0):

Check under Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs that you have configured a valid JRE >= 1.5

If it´s missing you should Add it or Search for it.